# MySQL: How to insert permanently an item into a table

Tags: mysql

I was trying to get info about the existence of an item, what I tried:

```
if mycursor.execute("SELECT * from Points WHERE PersonID=1234") == None:
    print("None")
else:
    print("Some")
```

And my previous line is

```
mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO Points(PersonID, Balance) VALUES(1234, 0)")
```

But, while I was trying this, I noticed that the **INSERT INTO** works only one time, since when I deleted this line hoping that it would work forever until it got deleted, how can I fix this? Is there a way?

Comment: your record is getting delete? Who is deleting it ?

Comment: Yes, I mean, when I close the programm and edit something, such as from

mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO Points(PersonID, Balance) VALUES(1234, 0)")

to

mycursor.execute("INSERT INTO Points(PersonID, Balance) VALUES(1235, 0)")

The thing changes when I use SELECT * FROM, and I dont get why, I though it should get saved somewhere, even if I close the terminal and run the programm again, but no

Comment: you have to commit the transaction, you are not committing it.

Answer (score 0):

maybe you should commit your changes on database. I don't know which library you are using. find some commit() api on your library